# MTP device detected under Linux but not under Windows

Tags: linux, windows, usb, drivers, mtp

I designed a board embedding a custom Linux built through buildroot. This board has a peripheral usb connector to appear like a device when connected to another OS.

A [MTP-responder python program](https://github.com/ali1234/pymtpd) is binded to the associated Usb Device Controller (Atmel USBA).

I'm able to detect the board as a MTP device under Linux with both libmtp v1.1.13 and nautilus. 
I'm also able to transfert files and share mountpoints through nautilus as if it was a MTP device like an Android phone for example.

---

However I'm not able to do the same under Windows 7 Professional, I installed [Microsoft MTP Porting Kit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19153) but my board is not recognized as a MTP device but as "Unknown Device".

I also tried to update driver through device manager following [this link](https://www.howtogeek.com/195607/how-to-get-your-android-device-to-show-up-in-file-explorer-if-it-isnt/) and selecting : 
"Update Driver Software" ==> "Browse my computer for driver software" ==> "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer" => "Android Device"

However at this point the only options I have are the following ones :

- Android ADB Interface
- Android Bootloader Interface
- Android Composite ADB Interface

I don't have any MTP device like in the link I gave.

---

I tried with my Android phone which was detected as a Mobile Device after I authorized connection on my phone.

---

This is really torturing me as I'm not used to Windows OS and it's working well under Linux. I can't make it work under Windows even if I installed MTP driver given by Microsoft.

Does anybody have a clue about detecting MTP devices which are not Android phones ? 
Or maybe there is a command line utility which could allow me to initiate communication with my board ?

---

***EDIT :*** After further research I've realized that Windows 7 should have MTP drivers built-in. So installing drivers was useless. 
However I'm still not able to communicate with my board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a way to make it work.

For those interrested in, here is the solution:

Under Windows device manager :

- Right click on the device and select "Update Driver Software"
- Select "Browse my computer for driver software"
- Select "Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer"
- In the left column, select "Standard MTP Peripheral"
- In the righ column, select "USB MTP Peripheral"

I almost had to try every possible option before it worked, hope it will help to save time for the next person facing this issue.